# How do I execute a function within a touchable opacity within a flatlist in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-native-flatlist

Each item within my flat list is a touchable opacity (an icon). I would like a function to execute when an icon is tapped. This function has been passed as a prop from the parent component and I'm passing the icon data into that prop. I thought this would be straight forward. However when I tap on the icon to open the modal that contains my flat list, the modal doesn't open and I get a warning: 'Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.' I'm confused because I'm executing a function that has been passed as a prop from my parent component. I'm unsure how else I am supposed to do it?

This is the function I want to call on tap (the changeIcon prop is the one causing the issues):

```js
function chosenIcon(selectedIcon) {
  props.changeIcon(selectedIcon);
  props.closeIconList(false);
}
```

This is the FlatList, and it doesn't seem to like me passing item.item.icon.

```html
<FlatList
  numColumns={3}
  data={ICONS}
  renderItem={(item) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={chosenIcon(item.item.icon)}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.item.icon}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

If I comment out the props.changeIcon line in the function and don't pass the data item.item.icon, everything works fine and the modal closes when I select an icon.

I hope that's clear enough! Thank you!

Comment: Well, the problem can appear because instead of passing the function into the `onPress` prop like that `onPress={() => chosenIcon(item.item.icon)}` you call it. For better understanding imagine that your function `chosenIcon` would return somethind as a result:
`function chosenIcon(selectedIcon) {
        props.changeIcon(selectedIcon);
        props.closeIconList(false);
        return  'sample of return'
}`

So in that case you will be passing 'sample of return' string into the `onPress` prop.
Hope that helps you

Comment: I see! Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add a fat arrow function to TouchableOpacity onPress callback.

```
 <FlatList 
    numColumns = {3}
    data = {ICONS}
    renderItem = {item => (
      <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.item} onPress= {()=> chosenIcon(item.item.icon)}> // add ()=>
         <Text style = {styles.text}>{item.item.icon}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
```